# Inherited objects share same table attribute in Lua

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua

I want to build a simple inheritance hierarchy in Lua. The `BaseClass` has two attributes, a single value `val` and a table `vals`. If I create two objects `foo` and `bar` of the `SubClass` and change these two attributes, changes of `val` work as expected, but for `vals` it seems like both objects share the same table internally.

```
BaseClass = {}

function BaseClass:new()
    o = {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    o.val = 0
    o.vals = {}
    return o
end

SubClass = BaseClass:new()

function SubClass:new()
    o = {}  
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

foo = SubClass:new()
bar = SubClass:new()
foo.val = 1
bar.val = 2
foo.vals[#foo.vals + 1] = 1
bar.vals[#bar.vals + 1] = 2
print(foo.val, bar.val)
print(#foo.vals, #bar.vals)
```

The code prints

```
1 2
2 2
```

How can I solve this? How do I create two different tables for `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: You have created separate value for `val` in this line: `foo.val = 1`.  But you have not created separate value for `vals`.  So, you are accessing old shared value stored inside base class.  To create separate value for `vals` for each object, either add `o.vals = {}` inside `Subclass:new` or add `foo.vals = {}` before using `vals`

Comment: But is there a way to do this inside the `BaseClass` scope? Because if `BaseClass` has multiple tables and I would create multiple derived objects it would be very messy to instantiate each table.

Comment: Do you want `vals` be completely individual for every object and share nothing?  Or do you want some fields in `vals` inherit from base class to all objects?

Answer (score 1):

Your `new` method does not distinguish between subclasses and instances. (I don't know why *Programming in Lua* does it this way.) One way to solve this is to have a separate method to make subclasses:

```
BaseClass = {}
BaseClass.__index = BaseClass

function BaseClass:new()
    o = {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    o.val = 0
    o.vals = {}
    return o
end

function BaseClass:subclass()
  local c = {}
  setmetatable(c, self)
  c.__index = c
  return c
end

SubClass = BaseClass:subclass()
```